# Nested Arrays Issue using Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

This has really stumped me, not sure why I cant get it working.

I have an a variable called 'posts'. Which contains the following.

```
array(2) { ["data"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["full_picture"]=> string(98) "https://www.website.com/picture.jpg" 
        ["message"]=> string(613) "long message here"
        ["id"]=> string(32) "000000000" } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["full_picture"]=> string(98) "https://www.website.com/picture.jpg" 
        ["message"]=> string(613) "long message here"
        ["id"]=> string(32) "000000000" } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
         ["full_picture"]=> string(98) "https://www.website.com/picture.jpg" 
        ["message"]=> string(613) "long message here"
        ["id"]=> string(32) "000000000" } 
    [3]=> array(3) { 
         ["full_picture"]=> string(98) "https://www.website.com/picture.jpg" 
        ["message"]=> string(613) "long message here"
        ["id"]=> string(32) "000000000" }  
    [4]=> array(3) {
        ["full_picture"]=> string(98) "https://www.website.com/picture.jpg" 
        ["message"]=> string(613) "long message here"
        ["id"]=> string(32) "000000000" } 
} 

["paging"]=> array(2) { 
    ["previous"]=> string(324) "website.com/link" 
    ["next"]=> string(306) "website.com/link" } 
}
```

I want to use twig to display the values in the nested arrays within the data array using twig markup.

At the moment I have the follow

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.data.message }}
{{ endfor }}
```

I have also tried the following with no success.

```
{% for key, post in posts %}
{{ post.data.message }}
{{ endfor }}
```

any guidance on where i am going wrong would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried both and they are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everyone. Once again it was a basic error by myself. I forgot to pass the variable through when rendering the page using slim.

The correct markup in the end was very basic

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.full_picture }}
{{ post.message }}
{% endfor %}
```

thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`Post` looks like this:

```
//<?php

$post = [
    'data' => [
        // 
        0 => [
            'full_picture' => 'https://www.website.com/picture.jpg',
            'message'      => 'long message here',
            'id'           => '000000000'
        ],
        // 1..3
        4 => [
            'full_picture' => 'https://www.website.com/picture.jpg',
            'message'      => 'long message here',
            'id' 
        ]
    ]
];
```

There's one more array in the way: `post.data[i].message`